# How can I open a Mac application like iTunes and read data from from it using Python?

Tags: python, macos, web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I saw a few ways to open an application using Python but none of them allow me to read the data from inside the application. Is this possible?

Comment: I am looking for a module similar to selenium that allows me to interact with my application just like I would do with a web page. I have tried opening applications using subprocess but am not able to interact with them.

Comment: If you're talking specifically about iTunes, you can copy the library with ctrl+A and paste it into a csv. Then you can use the `csv` module in Python to read the data in.

Comment: I actually want to interact with applications through Python and extract the data using Python directly.

Comment: Are you asking specifically for iTunes, or any general application?

Answer (score -1):

**Windows:**

You can interact with programs with [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

Also, check this out: [Interact with other programs using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288177/interact-with-other-programs-using-python)

You can interact with programs in Python using COM automation.

**Mac:**

[How can I interact with an application on mac through python subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010650/how-can-i-interact-with-an-application-on-mac-through-python-subprocess)

[How do I communicate between python and a mac application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392022/how-do-i-communicate-between-python-and-a-mac-application)

Comment: This answer is specific to Windows. The question is tagged [tag:osx].

Comment: A link-only answer which links to other SO questions isn't really appropriate, either. Nominate as a duplicate for one of them (probably the second one) is my suggestion.

Comment: @tripleee Got it. Thanks again! :)